# Get User details with user id Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I saw this example trying to get the User details from Firestore Firebase in Flutter. Unfortunately it gives me the error `The instance member 'snap' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

```
  DocumentSnapshot snap = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc().get() as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
  String myId = snap['name'];
```

Comment: Please include more from your code, where do you make these declarations?

Comment: Hey there, may I ask if either of the two answers worked for you? If it didn't, please let us know so we can try and assist you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can't use snap there because you have not initialized the object.

Rather, move the usage into initState. Something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc()
      .get() as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
  String myId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myId = snap['name'];
    // should be myId = snap.get('name');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call it using `async` and `await`

```
String myId = '';

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

void initialize() async{
  DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc().get() as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
  myId = snap['name'];
}
```